# Looping jQuery animation issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have been stuck on this for a while, and I really do not understand the best way to do what I am trying to do.

I have a 2 Divs, (Keep in mind i might need more). I want only div 1 to be displayed at first, then when I press an arrow on the first div, it slides to the left, and a second div appears (sliding in from the right). How would I do this to loop? I thought I could use css3, but that did not work very well.

Here is what I have got so far: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGqLw/2/)

This is the jQuery, but it only handles One arrow:

```
$('.arrow-right').click(function () {  
    // Slide div to left, and slide new from right ... repeat/Loop
    $("#div1").animate({
        left: "-999%"
    }, 1000, function () {
        $("div1").css("block", "none");
        $("div2").animate({
            // Animate Right Div from right to left ... 
        });
    });
});
```

I have gotten the animation from left to right, but I am just not understanding how I can loop this animation (like a slider) and make a button click for each div I have.

Am I on the right track? (My experiance in jQuery is very slim especially in animating)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is as close as I got to what I want, but I need it to loop, and I want to be able to add content without having to modify the jQuery too much.
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGqLw/10/)

Comment: There are plenty of jQuery plugins for sliders, and also heaps of tutorials if you want to go through them to learn the basic logic behind creating your own.

Comment: @ahren thanks. This is not a slider though. The Div is in the center screen. Like a modal, but the modal slides out and another one in. I am not wanting the image/content slider feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/jGqLw/9/**

Set a global variable to 'lock' the script when it is animating.

```
isAnimating = false;

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.arrow-left', function() {
    // Check if the lock is on, if it is, cancel additional clicks
    if(isAnimating) return;

    // Lock the buttons to avoid multiple user-interaction when script is animating
    isAnimating = true;

    // Get the current displayed div and the next div to be animated in
    var $current = $(this).parents('.MovingDiv');
    var $next = $(this).parents('.MovingDiv').next();

    // Animate the current div out
    $current.animate({
        left: "-999%" // Animate to the left
    }, 1000, function() {
        $current.css({
                // This doesn't really do anything important because the start point will be set again the next time the next time it is needed
                left: "999%"
            })
            .appendTo('.wrapper'); // move to end of stack

        // Animate the next div in
        $next.css({
                left: "999%" // set the start point from the right
            }).animate({
                left: "0%" // complete animation in the middle of the page
            }, 1000, function() {
                isAnimating = false; // unlock the script when done
            });
    });

}).on('click', '.arrow-right', function() {
    if(isAnimating) return;

    isAnimating = true;
    var $current = $(this).parents('.MovingDiv');
    var $next = $(this).parents('.MovingDiv').siblings().last();

    $current.animate({
        left: "999%"
    }, 1000, function() {
        $current.css({
            left: "-999%"
        });

        $next.prependTo('.wrapper') // move to front of stack
            .css({
                left: "-999%"
            }).animate({
                left: "0%"
            }, 1000, function() {
                isAnimating = false;
            });
    });
});
```

Changed your CSS to:

```
.MovingDiv:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.MovingDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. I will make sure to read this line by line and get a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Is there a way to swap the animations over? When i press right, the div goes left? etc.

Comment: Ah, ok, that is what i though, but i would have confused myself if i did something wrong LOL

Comment: Thank you sooo much... This helped even more.

Answer (score 1):

#### This will support any content.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/jGqLw/5/

You *were* on the right track. I'd try to set some `global variables` of the `widths` and whatnot that you need to actually need it to function with, rather than using `percentages` as it appears you did in your example.

**Here's an idea of the standard way to do it:**

```
var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});
```

Comment: I am not looking for a slider. I am looking to slide a div off the screen and another one from the right to the middle of the screen. Look at my example. The goes from center to left, and i need another div to come from the right to the center. And that needs to loop.

Comment: Easy enough. One moment.